# What is the proper translation for 'Dunnage', from English

Tags: traducción

I can't seem to find an obvious choice by browsing product literature, which is my usual tactic. This is the concept I want a Spanish word for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnage

Comment: I provided an answer, but I'm afraid is going to be an unsatisfactory one. If you could narrow a little bit more or give more context, probably better answers will be provided.

Comment: That was my confusion too, I'm creating a taxonomy of products and this category is so generic that there are many subtypes

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia itself has a link to the spanish translation: "Embalaje".

Comment: interesting answer; however, it would be good to expand it a bit more, since this is currently a bit more than a comment.

Comment: +1 Good response @Envite, it redirects to the actual answer and it's well explained there. I believe that the author of the question should have started by going to the Spanish version straight from Wikipedia as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede traducir como `material de relleno` o, en el caso de cargas, también `material de aseguramiento`.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish for `dunnage` seems to be `embalaje`. Both [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embalaje) and [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=dunnage) seems to translate it as such.

With the context provided

> inexpensive or waste material used to load and secure cargo during transportation

`embalaje` or `envoltorio` would work:

> recipiente o envoltura que contiene productos de manera temporal principalmente para agrupar unidades de un producto pensando en su manipulación, transporte y almacenaje

It could even be `relleno` if you are referring to the padding that sometimes is added to protect cargo (the *foam* that sometimes we call "corchopan" in Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably at the top of the taxonomic tree, why not name it with the common function?

If the sub branches refer to material used to just fill the spaces, maybe «relleno» can fit.

«Protección», «acolchado» or «amortiguación» if the case is to avoid damage or even (specially the latter two) movement.

If the taxon is very broad and there are branches of everything, just «embalaje» should do, if there are no separate taxons dedicated to packaging in general.

Comment: Commenting myself: maybe «protección» is the most suitable one? I'm reading a bit about dunnage and it's also used to keep moisture at bay too.

Comment: Again commenting myself: I see that my answer includes some answers already given by other users, so I guess they are who deserve the credit depending of which is your final choice.